# Problem to route to different components with Angular 8

Tags: angular-routing, angular8, angular-router

What I'm trying to do is to route to different components via the same path but it wont work.

```
/schedule -> shall load the ScheduleComponent
/schedule/123 -> shall load the EventComponent ('123' is a dynamic path, so that it is not an option to write it to children's path)
```

Here is the code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ScheduleComponent }    from './schedule.component';
import { EventComponent }       from '@app/modules/event/event.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '', 
    component: ScheduleComponent,
    children: [
        { 
            path: '**', 
            component: EventComponent 
        }
    ]
}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ScheduleRoutingModule { }
```

But I'm doing something wrong and cannot find the mistake, because the `EventComponent` is called in any case, even if there is no additional path given. What is wrong with my code?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified any routes in your code example.
The '**' path that you set is used for "page not found", in case a user navigates to a non existing route.

More on routes can be found in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router)

```
 const routes: Routes = [
       { path: '/schedule', component: ScheduleComponent },
       { path: '/schedule/:id', component: EventComponent },
    ];
```